# speeding up numpy code involving array slicing and broadcasting

Tags: numpy, optimization, numpy-ndarray, array-broadcasting, numpy-slicing

I have the following code:

```
x = sp.linspace(-2,2,1000)
z = sp.linspace(-1,3,2000)
X,Z = sp.meshgrid(x,z) 
X = X[:,:,sp.meshgrid]
Z = Z[:,:,sp.meshgrid]
E = sp.zeros((len(z),len(x),3), dtype=complex)

# e_uvect.shape = (2,N,2,3)
# En.shape = (2,N,2)
# d_cum.shape = (N,)
# pol is either 0 or 1

for n in range(N):
    idx = sp.logical_and(Z<d_cum[n], Z>=d_cum[n-1])        
    E += e_uvect[pol,n,0,:]*En[pol,n,0]*sp.exp(+1j*self.kz[n]*(Z-d_cum[n-1])+1j*self.kx*X)*idx
```

Basically the above is part of a code to calculate the electric field of an `N-`layer structures. For each iteration inside `for` loop, I find the index of the array elements which are within the `N`th layer, then after I calculate the electric field I multiply the whole thing by `idx` to 'filter' out the correct part which satisfies `sp.logical_and(Z<d_cum[n], Z>=d_cum[n-1])`.

It works fine, but I wonder if there is a more efficient way of doing this using numpy array slicing or other methods, because each multiplication involves a large proportion of array elements which are not accepted in each iteration. I tried something like the following to only work on the relevant part of the coordinates array `Z` and `X`

```
idx = sp.logical_and(Z<d_cum[n], Z>=d_cum[n-1]) 
Z2 = Z[idx]
X2 = X[idx]
E[???] += e_uvect[pol,n,0,:]*En[pol,n,0]*sp.exp(+1j*self.kz[n]*(Z2-d_cum[n-1])+1j*self.kx*X2)
```

But then `Z2` and `X2` becomes a 1d-array, and I'm not sure about the indexing part within `E` or how to reshape the arrays appropriately.

So are there any ways to speed up the original code?

Comment: Is `sp` `scipy`?  If so, why aren't you using the more common `import numpy as np`?

Comment: What's the approximate size of `N`?

Comment: `e_uvect[pol,n,0,:]*En[pol,n,0]` could be moved outside the loop, doing all `n` at once?  I'd look for other expressions like this, trying to simplify the contents of the iteration.  Once it's simple enough, you might see a way of eliminating the loop entirely.